# robots.txt for wordpress blog ( disallow /blog/page/... but allow to crawl there links to all posts?)

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, web-crawler

I have a very naive question I can't find an answer.
I have a wordpress blog.
All posts are listed in several pages, e.g.

```
mydomain.com/blog/
mydomain.com/blog/page/2/
...
mydomain.com/blog/page/N/
```

so I don't want a crawler to "remember" what was on particular page, but want to let it
crawl all posts linked on each "/page/", will it be able to follow and crawl links on pages I disallow with

```
disallow: /blog/page/ ?
```

Or how do I disallow crawling what posts are on particular page, but still let it crawl all posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with robots.txt. Your sample `Disallow` line would tell the crawler, "don't ever request a URL that starts with `/blog/page/`.

What you probably want to do is add a "noindex" [robots meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) to all of your /page/ pages. That tells Google, "don't index these pages," but allows the bot to crawl them and get links to individual blog entries.